# Orientation forms on compact smooth manifolds are equivalenf if they have the same integral

Tags: differential-forms, global-analysis

I have a problem solving the following exercise (Ex. 22-15) from John M. Lee‘s „Introduction to smooth manifolds“.

The problem is the following:
Use the same technique as in the proof of the Darboux theorem to prove the following theorem:
If $M$ is an oriented compact smooth $n$ manifold ($n\geq 1$) and if $\omega_0,\omega_1$ are smooth orientation forms with $\int_M\omega_0=\int_M\omega_1,$ then there exists a diffeomorphism $F:M\to M$ with $F^*\omega_1=\omega_0.$

For more context I‘ll quickly give an overview of the argument in the proof of the Darboux theorem:
Given two symplectic forms $\omega_0,\omega_1$ one could locally (in a coordinate ball) write
\begin{equation}
\omega_t:=(1-t)\omega_0+t\omega_1:=\omega_0+t\eta=\omega_0+td\alpha
\end{equation}(because $\eta$ is defined in a coordinate ball and closed and therefore exact).
Then one defines a time dependent VF in a open set where all $\omega_t$‘s are non-degenerate by 
\begin{equation}
V_t\lrcorner \omega_t=-\alpha_t
\end{equation}
and then calculates
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=t_0}\theta_{t,0}^*=\theta_{t_0,0}^*(d(V_t\lrcorner \omega_t)+\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=t_0}\omega_t)=0,
\end{equation}where $\theta_{t,0}$ is one of the time dependent flows of $V_t.$ This implies that
$\theta_{1,0}^*\omega_1=\omega_0.$

My problem when attacking the problem is now the following: 
As the problem is a global problem, I can‘t just write $\eta=\omega_1-\omega_0$ as the differential of a form $\alpha.$ If this would be possible, then the rest would be exactly the same because
\begin{equation}
\Gamma (TM)\ni X \mapsto X\lrcorner \omega \in \Omega^{n-1}(M)
\end{equation} is a smooth bundle isomorphism for each orientation form and because each $\omega_t$ is an orientation form for $0\leq t\leq 1.$

I would be glad for hints or solutions how to surpass my problem or for other approaches.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, $\omega_1-\omega_2$ is exact since $\int_M(\omega_1-\omega_2)=0$.

[If $\omega$ is an $n$-form on a compact $n$-manifold $M$ without boundary, then $\omega $ is exact if and only if $\int\limits_{M}\omega=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110966/if-omega-is-an-n-form-on-a-compact-n-manifold-m-without-boundary-then)

Comment: This helped. Thanks!