# About the exactness of $n$-forms

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

I have the following statement in my Analysis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ book:

> If $\omega$ is an $n$-form on a orientable compact $n$-manifold $M$ without boundary, then $\omega $ is exact if and only if $\int\limits_{M}\omega=0$.

In the comment on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110966/680679), it is mentioned that it is necessary that $M$ be connected. But in my book there is no comment on the need to be connected, can this be due to the definition of manifold?

I am particularly interested in the volume form, I have that the volume form cannot be exact, the problem comes from using Stokes, the volume form would be zero (because the boundary is empty), can I still state this if the manifold is disconnected?

> A manifold of dimension $m$ and class $C^k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a set $M\subset R^n$ that can be covered by a collection of open $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $V=U\cup M$ admits $C^k$ parameterization $\phi: V_0 \to V$ defined in an open $V_0\subset\mathbb{R}^m$

If I don't need connectivity because of my definition, what would be the definition that requires connectivity?

Answer (score 7):

The "only if" is fine, but the "if" requires connectedness. For consider the disjoint union of two spheres, and let $\omega$ be a form that integrates to $1$ on the first sphere and to $-1$ on the second. Obviously, such an $\omega$ cannot be exact. (Apply Stokes's Theorem on each sphere separately.)

Indeed, the argument I just gave answers your question about the volume form. It follows directly from the contrapositive of the "only if."